# Python 3 sort list -> all entries starting with lower case first

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
l1 = ['B','c','aA','b','Aa','C','A','a']
```

the result should be

```
['a','aA','b','c','A','Aa','B','C']
```

so same as l1.sort() but beginning with all words that start with lower case.

Comment: Take a look at the docs, please. It says that one can supply their own function to retrieve a list's element while doing comparisons inside a sorting algorithm.

Comment: your output list has more elements than your input list..?

Comment: What do `aA` and `Aa` come from? they don't exist in `l1`.

Comment: What exactly is your criteria for sorting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> l = ['B', 'b','a','A', 'aA', 'Aa','C', 'c']
>>> sorted(l, key=str.swapcase)
['a', 'aA', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'Aa', 'B', 'C']
```

## EDIT:

A one-liner using the `list.sort` method for those who prefer the imperative approach:

```
>>> l.sort(key=str.swapcase)
>>> print l
['a', 'aA', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'Aa', 'B', 'C']
```

## Note:

The first approach leaves the state of `l` unchanged while the second one does change it.

Comment: nice one, far better than mine

Comment: Nice one-liner. That is what I was looking for. Could you please add the the option l.sort(key=str.swapcase)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you might be looking for:

```
    li = ['a', 'A', 'b', 'B']

    def sort_low_case_first(li):
        li.sort()  # will sort the list, uppercase first
        index = 0  # where the list needs to be cuted off
        for i, x in enumerate(li):  # iterate over the list
            if x[0].islower():  # if we uncounter a string starting with a lowercase
                index = i  # memorize where
                break  # stop searching
        return li[index:]+li[:index]  # return the end of the list, containing the sorted lower case starting strings, then the sorted uppercase starting strings 

    sorted_li = sort_low_case_first(li)  # run the function
    print(sorted_li)  # check the result
    >>>  ['a', 'b', 'A', 'B']
```